# Can't receive value from ListView, while using setOnItemClickListener interface

Tags: java, android, retrofit, themoviedb-api

I'd want to take have a movie title from ListView by click on it. The data what I'm getting, is from api, served by retrofit. For now, I'm tried to use this interface

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String s = String.valueOf(listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
            Toast.makeText(genres_listView.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

But I've get some strange value, such as

```
com.example.myfilmguide.models.itemList_model$itemList_Results@21f3fae
```

How should I code it properly, to get the normal title?

@Edit

Here's the POJO class that you guys wanted.

```
public class itemList_model {
@SerializedName("total_results")
private int total_results;

@SerializedName("results")
private List<itemList_Results> results;

public List<itemList_Results> getResults() {
    return results;
}

public int getTotal_results() {
    return total_results;
}

public class itemList_Results{
    @SerializedName("name")
    String name;
    @SerializedName("title")
    String title;
    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    Double vote;
    @SerializedName("overview")
    String overview;
    @SerializedName("release_date")
    String releaseDate;
    @SerializedName("id")
    int id;

    public itemList_Results(String title, Double vote, String releaseDate, String overview) {
        this.title = title;
        this.vote = vote;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Double getVote() {
        return vote;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: override to string method of your model..

Comment: getItemAtPosition(int position) will give you object that you added in listView.

Comment: post your model you add in listView

Comment: show your model class

Comment: I'm just edited question.

Comment: @Aws check my answer.. i wish it will be helpul for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast the returning object and get the title field. Like in your case, 
The following output means:

```
com.example.myfilmguide.models.itemList_model$itemList_Results@21f3fae
```

You are getting itemList_Results object, when you click the item from list.

so just use the following way,

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            itemList_Results obj = (itemList_Results)listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(genres_listView.this,obj.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
com.example.myfilmguide.models.itemList_model$itemList_Results@21f3fae
```

You should pass **Model** data respect to **Position**

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

             Toast.makeText(genres_listView.this,arrayListOBJ.get(position).getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: why are you making new object here..?

Answer (score 0):

Just try replacing the

```
String s = String.valueOf(listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

with

```
String s = String.valueOf(listView.getItemAtPosition(position).getTitle());
//listView.getItemAtPosition(position).getMethod() if you want to get other values.
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have list of `itemList_Results`, so you can get selected item like below code.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            itemList_Results list_results = (itemList_Results) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, list_results.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```